# Strange char instead of accented letters in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, non-ascii-characters

I'm building a web application with Ruby on Rails.
At the moment I'm using Ruby 2.1.5 and Rails 4.

I have a problem with accented letters. For example in the database the title of one object contains the word: "piú".
In the database I see the correct letters, but when i print the result with Rails I get the following word: "piÃ¹"

I print the result with classic Rails tag, for example: "<%= @object.name %>"

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: I'm using mysql database, nothing special!

Comment: Your browser is using UTF-8 and mysql?

Comment: How can I check what encoding is my browser using? 
Anyway I have never had a problem with accent!

Comment: In case of chrome -> Tools -> More Tools -> codification, and try to make a query to your accented field and copy paste to a empty html